# EJB method takes more time to return after each call

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, jboss7.x

I'm observing an unusual behaviour and I would like to understand what is happening.

Imagine a simple setup.

First I have a stateless bean that just returns something:

```
@Stateless
public class SimpleService{
    private Map<String, String> map;

    @PostConstruct
    public init(){
        map = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public Map<String,String> getMap(){
        return map;
    }
}
```

Then I have a another stateless bean that does some processing

```
@Stateless
public class ProcessService{

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProcessService.class);
    private static final int MAX = 2000;

    @Inject
    private SimpleService simpleService;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void process(){
        final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++){
            simpleService.getMap();
        }
        final long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        log.info(MessageFormat.format("Process took {0} ms", end - start));
    }
}
```

Then I have a simple CDI bean to call the process method.

**Result:**

When I call the `process` method several times in a row, the process time keeps increasing:

```
Process took 900 ms
Process took 1,100 ms
Process took 1,200 ms
Process took 1,400 ms
```

And it keeps going up every time the method is called.

How can that be explained?

I'm using Java JDK 1.7.0_25 and JBOSS EAP 6.1.

**EDIT**

By the way, the only way to 'reset' the processing time for the method is to restart the server.

Comment: Did you test this with more than 4 iterations in a row and did the times always increase or are they about the same after a certain point?

Comment: yes I did more than 4, it just keeps going up. It this example I took it up to 5s for the same method (about 25 calls). Actually it could be interesting to note that often it decreases a little bit and then goes back up: 350ms, 340ms, 460ms, 450ms, 700ms, 680ms, 900ms etc... In the end it always end up increasing

Comment: I can't take this example very seriously when you are already breaking all rules by having a stateless bean with state. It is an interesting problem however, you'd expect the time to go down given runtime optimizations. Unfortunately it is impossible to see where the processing time is going in code that does almost nothing. At this point it would be interesting to file this as a bug to JBoss and see what happens with it.

Comment: @Gimby I don't think it's wrong to have a stateless bean with a private attribute initialised by the `PostConstruct`. You are guaranteed that this method is called before getting the instance. So I think this breaks the 'stateless' contract. To double check I have set the map as final and initialised it in the constructor. Same effect. Actually I even got rid of the map and just return null and the effect remains. Submitting a bug to jboss is a good idea thanks

Comment: The question is: what happens with that state after the instance is returned to the pool? If you do this you must also take control of cleaning it up. But better is to just not do it and keep all logic within the EJB method invocation where it belongs and rely on dependency injection for the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done testing with WildFly 8.1.0.Final and I get the following:

```
Process took 900 ms
Process took 600 ms
Process took 400 ms
Process took 300 ms
Process took 130ms
Process took 100ms
```

And then it stabilises itself around 90ms.

So I think we can safely assume that the original issue was a bug in JBoss AS 7 which was fixed in WildFly 8.1. More than fixed they even introduced some optimisation!

**EDIT!**

My apologies everyone, I made a wrong diagnostic. This error has nothing to the version of JBoss but was due by JRebel.

When I downloaded Wildfly, I didn't run it in debug mode with attached JRebel agent (which I was constantly doing with EAP 6.1). If I start JBoss EAP 6.1 without JRebel the problem doesn't happen.

I got so used to JRebel I forgot I had it switched on!

I will raise an issue with the JRebel team.

**EDIT 2**

JRebel team investigated and were able to reproduce the defect. It has been fixed in the nightly build and will be fixed in the next release (due August/September 2014)

Comment: This is quite a surprise- should it be reported to AS 7 team?

Comment: That is quite an interesting find! Do you have a link to the bug report so I may track its progress?

Comment: Thanks. Alas, its been sent to the dungeons of "please open a support ticket". Methinks someone wants you to pay for the fix. At this point, JBoss 7.x is a dead product to me and its time to move on to 8.1 or something else entirely.

Comment: That was unexpected! :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the same test, but create an interface SimpleService and current SimpleService will be something like SimpleServiceImpl which will implement SimpleService.
I would assume that cdi does some magic to wrap EJB.
Hmm.. or another thing could be try to use @EJB injection instead @Inject